# Moving a 3D object after rotation

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I'm having a problem with moving a 3D object after I apply a rotation. Both the move and rotation functions work perfectly on their own. But the problem is when I move an object after a rotation, the object doesn't follow the mouse and goes in weird directions. If anyone can see my flaw, I'd appreciate it. Thanks! Here's my code:

```
private void Rotate()
{
    double angle;
    bool willangle = Double.TryParse(AngleRot.Text.ToString(), out angle);
    RectangleVisual3D rect = (RectangleVisual3D)LastSelectedObject;
    AxisAngleRotation3D r = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), angle);
    RotateTransform3D rot = new RotateTransform3D(r, rect.Origin);
    rect.Transform = Transform3DHelper.CombineTransform(rect.Transform, rot);
    LastSelectedObject = rect as ModelVisual3D;
}
private void MoveObject(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (LastSelectedObject is RectangleVisual3D)
    {
        RectangleVisual3D rect = (RectangleVisual3D)LastSelectedObject;
        Point3D? origin = GetPoints(e);
        if (origin == null)
            return;
        rect.Origin = (Point3D)origin;
        LastSelectedObject = rect as ModelVisual3D;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope this help: The order of rotation and move is very important. If you move, then rotate, then it move according to the x,y,z co-ordinates. If you rotate, then move, then it will move according to the rotations co-ordinates.

Comment: Beaten out by a Internet glitch. To elaborate, it is important to track movement and rotations independently and apply them in in a Move From Origin and then Rotate sequence each time if these are going to be allowed independently. Allowing movements to apply on the newly rotated coordinate system can be useful though, such as if you were simulating flight, although I recommend even then using quaternions rather than the internal transforms.

Comment: Ok, so I need to update the coordinates after I rotate? I'm not sure how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Moving your object by setting its origin is generally a bad move. If your helper library ( I don't think Transform3DHelper is .Net? ) is doing matrix math in the basic way, then you're messing it up by setting rect.Origin.

Instead, try finding the distance vector moved and apply that translation matrix.

I'm assuming

> Vector2D dist=new Vector2D((oldPosition - newPosition).x, (oldPosition - newPosition).y);
>
> TranslateTransform3D trans = new TranslateTransform3D(dist.x,dist.y,0);
>
> rect.Transform = Transform3DHelper.CombineTransform(rect.Transform, trans);

The other possible error is that CombineTransform should reverse rect.Transform and rot, but I'm not sure if the API is handling that for you. See if an overloaded version of the method allows you to reverse those two.

Comment: It makes sense, and I tried doing that before I decided to just set the origin, but when I do it, the object just shoots out from the screen

Comment: The viewable window is usually measured in a -1,-1,-1 -> 1,1,1 box. Try dividing dist.x and dist.y by screen width/height appropriately. Use small (~.25) hardcoded translations to test. I don't know how they're doing projections, but translating a large z amount should proportionally shrink your object.

Comment: I've noticed that if I don't combine the two transforms (just typing rect.Transform = trans), it will move with the mouse. But the rotation is still messed up and when I move it after rotation, it will reset back to its original position

Comment: I think you want to move first. Use that as an input to the rotation so that it rotate around that position, and not the origin